# PWM signal generator circuit does not work in real life

Tags: pwm, duty-cycle, zero-crossing

I designed the motor soft start circuit in the figure below.

I ran the circuit in simulation programs, but when I tried it on a breadboard in real life, I could not get a PWM signal.

When I examined each component of the circuit, especially the LM339, which produces the PWM signal, I got a constant 12 volt output.

How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Trace the bad output to bad inputs and verify then report above those results. like bad connections or the analog voltages

Comment: e.g. for U2:A-1 to go low,  V-in>V+in

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. On schematics, please don't use four-way net junctions. From a distance, the junction dot may not be visible. That happens more these days when A3/A4 schematics are viewed on smartphones and tablets. With documentation, it's written/drawn once but read hundreds of times so that extra time spent reduces any misinterpretation, which makes everyone's life easier. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've been dealing with this circuit for weeks, unfortunately I couldn't get it to work. I examined the U2A (lm339) input connections (Vi-,Vi+), although I used a pull-up resistor, I could get 35mv. LM339s are not working as intended. If I find the solution to this problem, I think I can run the circuit.

Comment: You need to look at both comparators. if U2 pin 4 is 35mV then its because U2 p8 does not go lower p7 . Can you make that happen?

Comment: Did you checked out the Level circuit? Does R15 R16 and R17 something that will be replaced by a variable resistor?

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve your issue is to understand the circuit, estimate signals and check with real DMM measurements. As mentioned in question, I will assume  the regulated power supply is 12 V (Vcc).

Let´s see U2A: D3 anode will be around 0.6 V; bridge BR2 output will be Vac-2x0.8 (2 x diode voltage drop), if you measure this point, in R3 you will get this voltage reduced by 0.23; U2A output will be low when R3 voltage is over 0.6 V, that is most of time each half cycle, and the short time that is high, this signal will be limited by Vbe of  Q1, so you will measure a very low voltage; capacitor C2 will be discharged each 10 ms, and through R8 will be charged in this time up to 4.5 V peak, the average voltage will measure around 2 Volts.

The setup of U4A is a little confusing. Q4 looks like a constant current generator, but there is no resistor from base to ground to polarised this transistor, so it will only flow current during charging C7, at the startup. Once the capacitor is charged to Vcc, no current will flow and V(+) will be grounded. This is non inverting, gain 2 amplifier, so Vout ("level") will be also 0 V.

In stable condition, U2B will compare V(+) = 0 , and V(-) = saw signal of C2, positive most time of each half cycle, so most of the time Vout will low, and Q2 will be switched on, you will get +12 V in "PWM signal". You can see that 0 V signal in "level" will generate a constant 12 V "PWM signal" , and any "level" voltage over 4.5 V (peak voltage in capacitor C2) will correspond to constant 0 V in "PWM signal"